# How to use CSS transition for elements without positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
<button id="delete-row">delete</button>

<div id="a">
    <div class="row" style="height:150px;">Some content</div>
    <div class="row" style="height:150px;">Some content</div>
    <div class="row" style="height:150px;">Some content</div>
</div>
```

The height of the `a` div depends on how many `row` divs are inside it. Now I remove the middle `row`  with javascript and the `a` div changes automatically its height and the lower `row` moves up. What I wanna now is how to use Css transitions to make this change happening smoothly.

**I tried:**

```
#a{
transition-property: height;
transition-duration:0.5s;
}
```

And also I tried the code below, so I can make the lower `row` change the `top` property slowly but the case is that they are not positioned `relative` or `absolute` so they don't have any `top` property.

```
.row{
   transition-property: top;
   transition-duration:0.5s;
}
```

What property is here triggered when elements change their positions on page in case we don't use any positioning and the elements are positioned by the normal flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately CSS alone cannot achieve what you require. The `transition` property only applies when a property of an element is directly changed. In your case you remove an element, so the `height` of the `#a` div is changed by proxy when the child is removed.

Instead, you can use jQuery's `slideUp()` method to animate the height transition before removing the `.row`. Try this:

```js
$('#delete-row').click(function() {
  $('.row:eq(1)').slideUp(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  })
})
```

```css
#a { border: 1px solid #C00; }
.row { height: 150px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="delete-row">delete</button>

<div id="a">
  <div class="row">Some content</div>
  <div class="row">Some content</div>
  <div class="row">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can the eq(n) selector be used like nth child in css?

Comment: Just because the row divs are not always 3 in my case and they can reach a higher number i made some little changes to your code but otherwise, your solution was what I was looking for.